# How to configure network interface after installation of solaris 8

Tags: solaris

I already install Solaris 8 in my machine, in the installation I chose the option `not-networked` so I didn't configure any network interface or an IP address.
So can you please tell me how can I do this after finishing the installation of Solaris-8 with the terminal?

Comment: Solaris 8? Really?

Answer (score 2):

You should create files like /etc/hostname.qfe0 in format

```
192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

where 192.168.1.1 is the IP of this interface and 255.255.255.0 is the netmask for it. Also you should check

```
/etc/defaultrouter
/etc/inet/hosts
```

Please check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/fpdcn/index.html) document for more detailed info

Comment: You'll also probably want to populate /etc/resolv.conf so that you can resolve things via DNS.  And either editing the hosts search order in /etc/nsswitch.conf or followed by a `cp /etc/nsswitch.dns  /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Answer (score 1):

One approach (which the help of the Solaris installation itself hints to do if the network adapter is not available to configure initially), if you don't mind redoing some of the other configuration of the system, is to use `sys-unconfig`:

1. Shut down and install the network interface hardware if it isn't already
2. (Intel only) At the first stage boot loader, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to interrupt the autoboot and follow the prompts; with the network interface in the devices list, choose to boot from the HD, which will immediately lead to the second stage boot prompt
3. At the boot prompt, boot with `-r`— on Intel systems you'll have to get on the <kbd>b</kbd> key quite fast to cancel the default boot in my experience — to get Solaris to update the loaded drivers and rebuild the `/dev` entries.
4. Login as root, and verify that the lines related to the network interface hardware are now showing up in the `dmesg` output.
5. Run `sys-unconfig` and follow the prompts. This will reset the system to an unconfigured state and reboot, so that the normal first-boot configuration process (display resolution, network settings, time zone, etc.) will happen again.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using DHCP, you'll enter something like:

```
ipadm create-ip net0
ipadm create-addr -T DHCP net0/addr
```

You should be able to change the **net0** and **addr** after the slash.

If you're using static addressing, the first command will be the same, and you'll configure the static address as follows:

```
ipadm create-addr -T static -a local=X.X.X.X/Y net0/addr
```

**X.X.X.X** will be your static address and **Y**, your subnet mask.

DHCP should automatically configure your route and DNS settings, but if you're using static addressing, you'll need to add a DNS server to your **/etc/resolv.conf** and you'll need to set a default router in **/etc/defaultrouter**.

Comment: `ipadm` is a Solaris 11 command.  OP asked about Solaris 8.